# Always 'proxy_pass' and require 'auth_basic' on requests started with '/admin'. How to write the nginx config?

Tags: nginx

This is what I have. The problem is the proxy settings are duplicated. What's the better way to do it?

```
proxy_redirect off;

location / {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}

location /admin {
  auth_basic 'Restricted';
  auth_basic_user_file passwd;

  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
       proxy_pass http://backend;
   }

   location ~ ^/admin {
       auth_basic 'Restricted';
       auth_basic_user_file passwd;
   }


}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. /admin won't go through proxy_pass now. I also tried place `location ~ ^/admin` before the `if`, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
proxy_redirect off;

location / {
  try_files $uri @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
  if ( $uri ~* "^/admin/? ) {
    auth_basic 'Restricted';
    auth_basic_user_file passwd;
  }
  proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```